# Dart-Maven-Plugin execute pub get only

Tags: maven, dart, dart-pub

I am trying to write a maven pom file that only runs pub get.  However when I run mvn clean package, I get errors saying there is no main.dart file.  My dart project contains reusable dart classes that I just want packaged up to be imported elsewhere, so there is no main.dart file.  When I run pub get from the command line in that directory the packages are created.  Here is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.abc.comp</groupId>
  <artifactId>a_comp</artifactId>

  <name>a_comp</name>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.dzwicker.dart</groupId>
        <artifactId>dart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <pubCommand>get</pubCommand>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>pub-get</id>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>pub</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Is this trying to run something other than just "pub get"?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Edit:
Here is the maven log when I run mvn clean package.  I've also tried adding a src/main/dart

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building a_comp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ a_comp ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dart-maven-plugin:3.0.8:pub (pub-get) @ a_comp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.359 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-30T12:55:53-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/234M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.dzwicker.dart:dart-maven-plugin:3.0.8:pub (pub-get) on project a_comp
: Compiler-source-root 'C:\Users\s\Git Projects\project\a_comp\src\main\dart'  does not exist. -> [Help 1
]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Could you post your Maven log?